# Not able to upload image from gallery in Android 4.4

Tags: android, cordova, android-4.4-kitkat

I am trying uploading images which are gotten from gallery with the code below.

```
//imageUri is a uri which is gotten by Phonegap camera API 
//(use option Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY&&Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI) 
var imageUri = getImageUri();

//handlerUri is a uri to upload the image 
var handlerUri = getHandlerUri();

window.resolveLocalFileSystemURI(imageUri, function(fileEntry) {
    fileEntry.file(function(fileObj) {
        var fileName = fileEntry.name;
        var options = new FileUploadOptions();
        options.headers = {
            Connection: "close"
        };
        options.fileKey = "uploadfiles";
        if (fileName.indexOf('/') > -1) {
            options.fileName = fileName.substr(fileName.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
        } else {
            options.fileName = fileName;
        }

        options.mimeType = "image/jpeg";
        options.chunkedMode = false;
        options.params = params;

        var ft = new FileTransfer();
        imageUri = fileEntry.nativeURL;

        ft.upload(imageUri, handlerUri,
            function(r) {
                if (r.response == "success") {

                } else {

                }
            },
            function(error) {},
            options, true);
    }, function(error) {

    });
}, function(error) {

});
```

For devices below Android 4.4, the app works well. However, in Android 4.4 KitKat, the same code does not work anymore.

Note: I have only gotten a code 3 error in LogCat after long time uploading. Someone says that code 3 is a connection error but it should not be my condition because the same code works well below Android 4.4.

Could anyone help?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you indent / format / tidy up your codes? Any error shown in LogCat ?

Comment: code 3 is CONNECTION_ERR, it doesn't matter if it works in other android versions. The CONNECTION_ERR is called when an IOException is catched, so the server isn't returning a 200. It can be a bug on the file transfer plugin, fill an issue on the cordova JIRA.

Comment: @jcesarmobile any suggestion to find the root in the native plugin? I have already created a native Android project and I think I can fix the bug.

Comment: Not sure how to fix, but you can log the conn.getResponseCode(); on FileTransfer.java to see the server's response code, maybe that might help you locating the problem

Comment: @jcesarmobile Thanks, I will have a try and come back later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have finally worked it out by myself. It seems that the wrong file name is the root.
When I get the file name with the old code

```
var fileName = fileEntry.name;
```

the file name is 7962 which is not correct.

I use the code below to resolve this issue:

```
var fileName = fileEntry.nativeURL.substr(fileEntry.nativeURL.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
```

Thanks for all guys.

Comment: Thank u very much Jack its worked for me in android 4.4